# when batch size is greater than input image sample size for regression task in keras how it pick the images for the batch from the input images?

Tags: keras, regression, batchsize

so what I am trying to ask for eg: if input images is 5 and batch size is 12 so how it will pick the images from the sample like in what fashion in keras internally for regression problem?
Is it going to pick like this
epoch 1 - batch - 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2
epoch 2 - batch - 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4
Also if you can refer me to some documentation that can be helpful too
Any help is appreciated.